# 2014 Ford F150 V8 5.0L

Tags: ford, f-150

Hello i would like to know if we can pump gas vapur through the port/fuel injectors like gas liquid passes . I want to turn my v8 5.0L in to a vapur operated port injectors system and if possible routing the exhaust back in to the motor via intake snice the exhaust heat would not enter fear with the fuel sncie its port injected ??.. i get 16.8 km per liter but looking in to turning it in to a much cleaner emissions with a much better fuel mileage on top

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You are saying you want to port the exhaust back into the engine? And the question is, will it run? Can you expound upon your question and idea a little more, please?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Modern injectors are designed for liquid injection.  The presence of gas of any sort will not be easily be injected due to the compression of the gasses.

There would not be any easy metering of fuel quantity of a mix of fuel and gasses.

Routing exhaust gas back into the engine is *only* useful for reducing NOX emissions, by reducing combustion temperature.  There *should* be nothing useful in exhaust that is combustible, unless your engine is operating in a very rich condition.

The only potentially viable component of exhaust gasses in a good running IC engine is the heat, which can be harnessed by turbocharging.

If there is excess hydrocarbons in the exhaust that are not utilized, this is a sign of an engine out of tune.